# Code to reliably trigger alias errors?

Tags: c, gcc

Title pretty much says it all. Can someone direct me to or provide me with some code that will reliably trigger alias errors with somewhat recent versions of gcc? The reason i am asking is that i am trying to study the effects of strict aliasing but no matter how hard i try to violate it gcc will always come up with the "correct" result making any tests on how to deal with cases where you want to break the rules pretty much useless. I am not asking about warnings (-Wstrict-aliasing=2 gives warnings on pretty much everything i do) but code that actually fails when being optimized with -fstrict-aliasing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct mystruct_s {
    uint32_t int1;
    uint32_t int2;
} mystruct_t;

typedef mystruct_t __attribute__( ( may_alias ) ) mystruct_alias_bad1_t;
// warning: ignoring attributes applied to ‘struct mystruct_s’ after definition [-Wattributes]
// so basically gcc is telling me i have to define it again if want an aliasable
// version?

typedef struct mystruct_alias_s {
    uint32_t int1;
    uint32_t int2;
} __attribute__( ( may_alias ) ) mystruct_alias_t;

static __attribute__( ( optimize( "no-strict-aliasing" ) ) ) void myfunc1_alias1( void ) {
    uint32_t var, *i = &var;
    float *f = (float*)&var;
    // warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    // so __attribute__( ( optimize( "no-strict-aliasing" ) ) ) is either
    // not doing anything or gcc still gives warning even if the
    // optimization does not actually happen 

    *i = 100;
    printf( "[test-5] %u", var );
    *f = 0.f;
    printf( " %u (%s)\n", var, var != 100 ? "OK" : "FAIL" );
}

#pragma GCC optimize "no-strict-aliasing"
static void myfunc1_alias2( void ) {
    uint32_t var, *i = &var;
    float *f = (float*)&var;
    // warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    // this seems to be identical to the 
    // __attribute__( ( optimize( "no-strict-aliasing" ) ) ) case

    *i = 100;
    printf( "[test-6] %u", var );
    *f = 0.f;
    printf( " %u (%s)\n", var, var != 100 ? "OK" : "FAIL" );
}
#pragma GCC optimize "strict-aliasing"

static void myfunc1( void ) {
    uint32_t var, *i = &var;
    float *f = (float*)&var;
    // warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    // conclusion: pretty much none. all 3 functions generate exatcly the same
    // code that does just work as expected with no breakage at all despite the
    // warning so no-strict-aliasing on a per function level might do nothing
    // at all or just not for this code - no way to really tell...

    *i = 100;
    printf( "[test-7] %u", var );
    *f = 0.f;
    printf( " %u (%s)\n", var, var != 100 ? "OK" : "FAIL" );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    unsigned char buf[sizeof( mystruct_t )] = { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02 };

    // obvious rule violation:
    printf( "[test-1] int2 == %08X\n",
        ( (mystruct_t*)buf )->int2
        // warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    );
    // prints: [test-1] int2 == 2020202

    // pretty much the same as above but avoiding the struct:
    printf( "[test-2] int1 == %08X, int2 == %08X\n",
        *(uint32_t*)buf,
        // warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
        ( (uint32_t*)buf )[1]
        // warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
        // (you need -Wstrict-aliasing=2 - just -Wstrict-aliasing is not enough)
    );
    // prints: [test-2] int1 == 1010101, int2 == 2020202

    // lets try telling gcc that it should respect what we are trying to do:
    printf( "[test-3] int1 == %08X, int2 == %08X\n",
        ( ( __attribute__( ( may_alias ) ) mystruct_t*)buf )->int1,
        // warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
        ( (mystruct_alias_t*)buf )->int2
        // this is the only one that works so far but it seems there is no way
        // to cast to such a pointer on the fly - you have to apply this
        // attribute to the original struct...
    );
    // prints: [test-3] int1 == 1010101, int2 == 2020202

    // lets try to be creative (basically make a mess with C99 anonymous arrays):
    printf( "[test-4] int1 == %08X, int2 == %08X\n",
        ( (  __attribute__( ( may_alias ) ) mystruct_t* [1] ) { (mystruct_t*)buf } )[0]->int1,
        // warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
        // (you need -Wstrict-aliasing=2 - just -Wstrict-aliasing is not enough)
        // seems the attribute is ignored just as silently as for the direct cast
        ( ( mystruct_t* [1] ) { (mystruct_t*)buf } )[0]->int2
        // warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
        // (you need -Wstrict-aliasing=2 - just -Wstrict-aliasing is not enough)
        // i guess that evades -Wstrict-aliasing since that seems to pretty
        // much seems to only warn about code that casts and dereferences in one
        // go
    );
    // prints: [test-4] int1 == 1010101, int2 == 2020202

    // lets try to use __attribute__ optimize to disable strict aliasing temporaly:
    myfunc1_alias1();

    // lets try pragma:
    // #pragma GCC optimize "-fno-strict-aliasing"
    // error: #pragma GCC optimize is not allowed inside functions
    // (at least if you uncomment that line) so lets try a function again:
    myfunc1_alias2();

    // lets check if compiling the function without any makeup makes a difference:
    myfunc1();

    return 0;
}
```

Final edit:

I do not really have time to update the code right now but i have tried the different approaches of avoiding strict aliasing with the code mnunberg provided with the following results:

```
__attribute__( ( may_alias ) )
```

Works but only when added to to the actual structure definition (does not seem to matter which one you choose) - elsewhere its silently ignored.

```
__attribute__( ( optimize( "no-strict-aliasing" ) ) )
```

As suspected this has no effect at all. The program still hangs.

```
#pragma GCC optimize "no-strict-aliasing"
```

Also as suspected this does the same as the one above (nothing).

Comment: A title *never* "says it all"...

Comment: @tod Sorry, i assumed there was a somewhat standard way to test this. I edited the question to include the code i am working on. I would like to see at least test-7 fail but it just does not regardless of compiler switches.

Comment: @user3647627 What do you mean by *i am trying to study the effects of strict aliasing*, did you read the standard?, that would be the first thing to do.

Comment: @self Yes i have read the relevant parts and as i understand it it pretty much says i shall not alias pointers (with tiny exceptions for unions, char pointers and pointers of similar types). I am usually fine with this but there are cases where i do not see how i can realistically avoid it (my real offender is some generic linked list code). I would really consider -fno-strict-aliasing for list.c but as lots of it is inlined all over the place that would mean -fno-strict-aliasing pretty much for the whole project and i do not really like that idea so i am studying ways of defining exceptions.

Comment: `-fno-strict-aliasing` is an acceptable restriction/imposition to place among your project compilation flags.

Comment: @mnunberg Good to hear that since i have a feeling that is what i will end up with. At least i can say i have tried to avoid it.

Comment: The key to triggering an aliasing failure is understanding what kinds of optimizations could be made if those two pointers did not alias the same memory address. It's quite surprising test-7 fails, but not impossible. Disassembly might even show you not even dealing with pointers but having gcc simply place the values into the registers themselves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program, while not very useful, demonstrates GCC's aliasing very nicely. In the optimized version of the code, GCC sees that `bp->a` is never changed and optimizes the ENTIRE PROGRAM to just be a busy loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *a;
    char *b;
} s_v;
typedef struct {
    char *a;
    char *b;
} s_b;

static inline void do_foo(s_v *buf, s_b *bp)
{
    buf->a = (char*)0x010;
    buf->b = (char*)0x020;
    bp->a = buf->a;
    bp->b = buf->b;
    while (bp->a) {
        buf->a--;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    s_v *buf = malloc(sizeof (s_v));
    s_b *bp = (s_b*)buf;
    do_foo(buf, bp);
    return 0;
}
```

Assembly output (objdump)

```
  4003c0:   eb fe                   jmp    4003c0 <main>
  4003c2:   90                      nop
  4003c3:   90                      nop
```

GCC:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.3-4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc --with-cloog --enable-cloog-backend=ppl --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-ppl-version-check --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i586 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (Debian 4.7.3-4)
```

Comment: Just tested it and it hangs "beautifully" as long as any optimization level above 0 is specified (just -fstrict-aliasing does not do it). I guess it will be a little tricky to make it into a test since even just adding printf to the loop seems to "cure" it but i guess at worst i could wrap it into a thread or something so this is pretty much what i have been looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since your program invokes undefined behavior( reading invalid memory ), the strict aliasing doesn't really matter and the code doesn't demonstrate anything.

Comment: It starts at: buf + sizeof( *buf ).

Comment: @self i am not sure i understand where you are hinting with this but if you mean that there really is no way around that what i am trying to do is forbidden by the standard i agree with you. I do not fancy compiler specific workarounds to break the standard either (be it -fno-strict-aliasing or any other way to get aliasable pointers). Sad thing is unions do not really do it in some situations i fear.

Comment: @user3647627 If you search a bit regarding strict aliasing, the general consensus seems to be that the standard is broken and GCC adopted an unnecessarily literal stance on it.

Comment: The line `bp->a = buf->a;` will cause ub.

Comment: i tried "gcc -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -o alias2 alias2.c" vs "gcc -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -o alias2 alias2.c" with the code mnunberg posted. Only the second one hangs. Interestingly gcc issues no aliasing warning at all here though.

Comment: @mnunberg Make me happy?? How does my emotional state play any role with your answer. Code had an error and I pointed it out. This is a technical site where answers are subjected to review.

Comment: I'm not wrong, you didn't allocate enough memory for the larger struct and then you read invalid memory.

Comment: @mnunberg Yes, i came across a lot of annoyed people during my research. Especially Linus Torvalds is always fun to read when he is annoyed at something. I just did not want to instantly reject it. Somewhat related: I also came across the "restrict" keyword which seems to some kind of local strict aliasing hint. So maybe -fno-strict-aliasing + restrict in places where you think its really save to make that assumption might also be something i will be considering.

Comment: `restrict` will actually achieve the opposite result :) -- it's related. It basically tells the compiler that the address pointed to by the `restrict` pointer is not aliased by anything else in the function. Aliasing optimizations work by the compiler assuming that a pointer `T1*` will not reference the same memory location as `T2*`. If you have two `T1*` pointers then the compiler must assume that they _may_ reference the same address in memory _unless_ they are declared with `restrict` which tells the compiler that they will _never_ alias

Comment: (removed some of the earlier comments as they were not related to the general discussion of the topic)